# MS SQL trigger instead of update ELSE possible to execute original query?

Tags: sql-server

Here is my trigger

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[tri_before_update]
   ON  [dbo].[test]
   instead of update
AS 
BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 if update (test_a)
 begin
  *.. my update & insert query*
 end
END


create TRIGGER [dbo].[tri_before_update_price] 
  ON [dbo].[co_ticket] 
  instead of update 
AS 
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON; 
  if update (t_price) 
  begin 
     insert into old_price_log (t_id,insert_time,process_id,old_t_price) 
      select i.t_id,getdate(),2,t_price 
      from Inserted i,co_ticket t where i.t_id = t.t_id 
     update t set t_price = i.t_price 
      from co_ticket t, inserted i 
      where t.t_id = i.t_id 
  end 
  else 
  begin 
    -- if update other then (t_price) then the update comand not execute. 
    -- example when i update t_cancel_flag or t_quantity and etc. end 
  END
```

This trigger execute perfectly when i update on column "test_a". HOWEVER, when i update other than column "test_a" it won't be execute. I know i can put "else" command, but i got a lot of column. sometimes will update two other column , sometimes three or four column. I don't wish to update all column everytime. Is it possible ELSE "then execute original query"?
I tried a lot different way but still can't work. :( Please HELP!

Comment: You are defining an 'after' trigger which would conditionally do *only* the insert. Why did you choose an instead-of trigger?

Comment: because i need to keep existing "test_a" value into log before update it. is there any better way?

Comment: Define `I need to keep existing "test_a" value into log`. Post the exact table structure and the exact T-SQL you use, along with example usage. don't 'describe' the problem.

Comment: create TRIGGER [dbo].[tri_before_update_price]
   ON  [dbo].[co_ticket]
   instead of update
AS 
BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON;
if update (t_price)
begin


 insert into old_price_log (t_id,insert_time,process_id,old_t_price)
 select i.t_id,getdate(),2,t_price
 from  Inserted i,co_ticket t
 where i.t_id = t.t_id

 update t set t_price = i.t_price from co_ticket t, inserted i where t.t_id = i.t_id

end
else
begin
--- if update other then (t_price) then the update comand not execute. example when i update t_cancel_flag or t_quantity and etc.
end

END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[tri_on_update_price] 
  ON [dbo].[co_ticket] 
AS 
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON; 
  if update (t_price) 
  begin 
     insert into old_price_log (t_id,insert_time,process_id,old_t_price) 
      select d.t_id, getutcdate(),2,d.price 
      from deleted d
  END
end
```

An ordinary after trigger will do just what you want: insert a log of the price change, if the price was updated. No need for INSTEAD  OF. You need to look into the `deleted` [pseudo-table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) to get the old price. Never store local times in a database.

Comment: May i know anything should i put above "AS". Because if i didn't put anything, it occur error, however if i put "after update" then i juz will keep new price.

Comment: ah! my mistake, put "after update" then it works! i join table then should update deleted.price not o.price! I learn something new! "Deleted" it's so useful! Thank you so much for this two days help! :)